# Joule SAP Digital Assistant Integration - Context provision

Tags: sap

Is there a way we can set custom attributes in Joule Integration script while providing botname and url and other parameters and then access that attribute in Joule capability. The reason is we want to generalise the assistant by providing a context to Joule when app is loaded so that it knows from which app it is being called.

I tried setting custom attributes but could not read them in Joule Capability